# How to pass a python object to C extension and call its method inside?

Tags: python, python-c-extension

say I have a python object "o" with a method "m()", and I want to pass it as:

```
PyObject *f(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
  PyObject *o;
  PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &o);
  //o.m();
}
```

Apparently the last commented line doesn't compile, and I wonder whether there is a way I can achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`PyObject_CallMethod()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#PyObject_CallMethod).